# Xcode 4 automatic parenthesis close

Tags: xcode

Is there any way I can achieve automatic parenthesis close when I use Xcode 4?
I have googled that extensively but the only thing I have found was automatic closing braces only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Not sure if thats possible, I think the only reason they added the auto-closing curly brackets was because of things like:

```
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {

}
```

Or:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```